# Cant generate java code from wsdl file

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl, wso2

First I created simple web service with java and then generated wsdl for that web service and tested with SoapUI so it works fine. After that now  I am tring to generate java classes from wsdl file which was generated previously.

Here is the my pom.xml file configuration.

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <artifactId>webService</artifactId>
            <groupId>WebService</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>contractFirst</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>contractFirst</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <cxf.version>2.2.3</cxf.version>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <!-- Generate Java classes from WSDL during build -->
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/OrderProcess.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add generated sources - avoids having to copy generated sources to build location -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build the JAR with dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        </build>


    </project>
```

When I tried to generate it I am getting error like this.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project contractFirst: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/OrderProcessService.java:[24,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/OrderProcessService.java:[73,61] error: variable-arity methods are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable variable-arity methods)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/ProcessOrderResponse.java:[29,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/ObjectFactory.java:[24,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/ObjectFactory.java:[66,22] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/Order.java:[31,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/ProcessOrder.java:[28,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    [ERROR]
```

So I dont understed what is this **- source 5** thing is ?

**Update** :According to @Simze's answer above error is disappeared. Now I am geeting this error.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project contractFirst: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/OrderProcess_OrderProcessPort_Server.java:[17,34] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] symbol:   class OrderProcessImpl
    [ERROR] location: class demo.order.OrderProcess_OrderProcessPort_Server
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project contractFirst: Compilation failure
    /home/contractFirst/target/generated/src/main/java/demo/order/OrderProcess_OrderProcessPort_Server.java:[17,34] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class OrderProcessImpl
      location: class demo.order.OrderProcess_OrderProcessPort_Server
```

**wsdl file**

Comment: Which version of maven you're using?

Comment: I am using maven 3.0.5 and java 1.7

Comment: Does you'r JAVA_HOME set correctly?

Comment: Yes indeed. I have installed only 1.7. So there wont be conflit with java version

Comment: Check my answer, let me know if it works

Comment: That error is gone. Now I am getting another error.New  error message  was added.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution for this.
When we are generating java code for given wsdl file we need to specify what are to be generated in the configuration section of **cxf-codegen-plugin**

```
...
   <wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/OrderProcess.wsdl</wsdl>
        <extraargs>
            <extrrg>-impl</extrrg>
            <extrrg>-server</extrrg>
        </extraargs>
    </wsdlOption>
    </wsdlOptions>
 .....
```

Here **-impl** means this will generate the service implementation class and **-server** is used to generate server component which can be used to publich the service.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting because, you're trying to run maven under Java 1.3, which doesn't support annotations. Please add below tags under `<build>` element which will solve your problem.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: After adding this plugin part previous error is disappeared. But I am getting a another error. Updated question

Comment: Then you need to post correct code to resolve the issue? Have you declared that variable?

Comment: shall I add the wsdl file ?

Comment: It's not related to wsdl it's related to java code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Java 1.5 or higher. This is what the compiler error is telling you when it says - source 5 thing because annotation support was added to Java from Java 1.5 onwards.